# Right align address

Tags: horizontal-alignment, letters

I am pretty new to LaTeX and I'm having some issues for creating a motivation letter. I have a nice structure in my mind, but I can't complete it fully.

Here's a live example: [click](https://www.writelatex.com/1654049kzdqnz). Everything looks fine, but the only issue I'm still having is that I want the `\address{}` field contents to display aligned to the right, instead of being inside a block aligned to the right but contents aligned to the left.

I've searched for the solution but haven't come across anything working.

Comment: you can wrap the address in the environment `\begin{flushright} ... \end{flushright}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The problem with that approach is that it wants to left-align the `\address` portion with the date portion.  So you end up with a right-aligned address that is left-aligned with the date.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- drat, i keep forgetting that `\address` contains `flushleft` (or the equivalent).  but there should be a way around that: patch the line in the definition of `\opening` that has `\begin{tabular}{l@{}}` to instead have `{r}` as the alignment.  (i'll make this an answer if i see any interest, by upvote to this comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I used a right-aligned `\Longstack` to accomplish it, but there were several quirks (EDITED to handle long and short name conditions):

1) I had to place the stack in a right-aligned box of the same width as `\today`, to handle cases when the name was either longer than *or* shorter than the date;

2) I had to explicitly set the `\Longstack` gap as 12pt, because `\baselineskip` was zeroed inside of `\address`.

In the MWE below, you can uncomment the extended part of the name, to see that it works for long names, too.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-0.3in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{2cm}

\longindentation=0pt

\signature{My Name}

\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{12pt}
\address{\makebox[\widthof{\today}][r]{\Longstack[r]{\textbf{My %very long 
  name}\\address\\phone\\email}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{}

\opening{\textbf{Job title goes here}}

Dear mister M,

Vivamus consectetur, mauris sit amet pharetra pharetra, tortor ante dignissim purus, vitae pellentesque ante lorem eu magna. Morbi at leo leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed feugiat volutpat risus, a ullamcorper magna dictum quis. Nam dictum enim et lectus consectetur consectetur. Vestibulum vitae eros vel elit venenatis ornare ac sed felis. Nunc et laoreet libero. Cras ut fermentum dui.

Vivamus consectetur, mauris sit amet pharetra pharetra, tortor ante dignissim purus, vitae pellentesque ante lorem eu magna. Morbi at leo leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed feugiat volutpat risus, a ullamcorper magna dictum quis. Nam dictum enim et lectus consectetur consectetur. Vestibulum vitae eros vel elit venenatis ornare ac sed felis. Nunc et laoreet libero. Cras ut fermentum dui.

Vivamus consectetur, mauris sit amet pharetra pharetra, tortor ante dignissim purus, vitae pellentesque ante lorem eu magna. Morbi at leo leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed feugiat volutpat risus, a ullamcorper magna dictum quis. Nam dictum enim et lectus consectetur consectetur. Vestibulum vitae eros vel elit venenatis ornare ac sed felis. Nunc et laoreet libero. Cras ut fermentum dui.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

I look forward to your reply.

\vspace{2\parskip} % Extra whitespace for aesthetics
\closing{Sincerely,}
\vspace{2\parskip} % Extra whitespace for aesthetics

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to align the address correctly, but unfortunately the date itself isn't aligned to the right. [Example.](https://www.writelatex.com/1654049kzdqnz) Is there a fix for this?

Comment: @arbitter I am not sure what you mean.  The right hand edge of the adress, the date, and the letter paragraphs all line up vertically.

Comment: @arbitter  To better see this, add the line `\hfill\smash{\rule{1pt}{8in}}` to the end of the last line of the letter, as in `I look forward to your reply.\hfill\smash{\rule{1pt}{8in}}`

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still seeing the issue in my example I provided in previous comment. Here's a printscreen: http://i.imgur.com/UXhx70V.png

Comment: @arbiter I see that the problem arises because your name is longer than the date.  Let me see if I can think of a fix for a long named alternative.

Comment: @arbiter Fixed.  See revision.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `tabular` to defined the address, and to get the date to also be right aligned you can redefined `\@date`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\signature{My Name}

\makeatletter
\let\Date\@date
\renewcommand{\@date}{\hfill\Date}%
\makeatother

\address{\begin{tabular}{r@{}}%
    \textbf{My name is pretty long}\\
    address                        \\
    phone                          \\
    email                          \\
    \phantom{\today}              \\
    \end{tabular}%  
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{}

\opening{\textbf{Job title goes here}}

Dear mister M,
 
Vivamus consectetur, mauris sit amet pharetra pharetra, tortor ante dignissim purus, vitae pellentesque ante lorem eu magna. Morbi at leo leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed feugiat volutpat risus, a ullamcorper magna dictum quis. Nam dictum enim et lectus consectetur consectetur. Vestibulum vitae eros vel elit venenatis ornare ac sed felis. Nunc et laoreet libero. Cras ut fermentum dui.

Vivamus consectetur, mauris sit amet pharetra pharetra, tortor ante dignissim purus, vitae pellentesque ante lorem eu magna. Morbi at leo leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed feugiat volutpat risus, a ullamcorper magna dictum quis. Nam dictum enim et lectus consectetur consectetur. Vestibulum vitae eros vel elit venenatis ornare ac sed felis. Nunc et laoreet libero. Cras ut fermentum dui.

Vivamus consectetur, mauris sit amet pharetra pharetra, tortor ante dignissim purus, vitae pellentesque ante lorem eu magna. Morbi at leo leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed feugiat volutpat risus, a ullamcorper magna dictum quis. Nam dictum enim et lectus consectetur consectetur. Vestibulum vitae eros vel elit venenatis ornare ac sed felis. Nunc et laoreet libero. Cras ut fermentum dui.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

I look forward to your reply.
\hfill\smash{\rule{1pt}{8in}}

\vspace{2\parskip} % Extra whitespace for aesthetics
\closing{Sincerely,}
\vspace{2\parskip} % Extra whitespace for aesthetics

\end{letter}
 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using:

```
\address{Name Surname\\
 School of XYZ\\
 Location\\
 State Zip Code, Country\\
 name.surname@...com}
```

just comment out a few lines and use the     \flushright environment, as per below:

```
\begin{flushright}
%\address{
    Name Surname\\
     School of XYZ\\
     Location\\
     State Zip Code, Country\\
     name.surname@...com
%}
\end{flushright}
```